# Boolean to check if a name attribute exists in node.js

Tags: node.js

Been struggling with this one.

I just want a way to check if, for example, a name attribute of 'price' exists on a page. And it should just return true or false. And it has to work in node.js.

So, I have a webpage. On it there is an input form. It will have a name attribute. The name attribute will have some value, for example 'price' [name='price']. I would like some way in node.js to check whether [name='price'] attribute is there or not.

Comment: I edited my question. Hopefully it provides more clarity.

Comment: nodejs is use for server side programming. Do you mean javascript instead?

Comment: No, I mean on node.js I wanted to make the question as simple as possible so I didn't include a lot of details on why I need this. Basically I am using an async.whilst function, and it takes a test parameter. The test has to return either true or false. So, I need something that gives a true or false answer to the question of whether there exists a certain attribute with a certain value on the webpage.

Comment: Then I would suggest refractoring your question as it does not give much context. Probably show us a snippet of your code that you think it is critical in solving the problem.

Comment: node.js by itself does not "have" a web page (those are in the browser).  A node.js server will be sent the contents of a form when a form is posted from a web page.  Is that when you're trying to detect the name attribute?  If so, please **post the HTML of the form** so we can see what will be sent to the server.  If you can also **post the relevant server code that is receiving the form**, that will allow us to offer a better and more complete answer in context.

Comment: FYI, questions here on stack overflow nearly always get better answers when you post very specific code (and HTML if needed).  General questions with no code and not a lot of details are hard to provide good answers to.  Complete answers often require an extensive tutorial which is not what stack overflow is good at and is beyond the scope of what most people will do for you.  Very specific questions are   generally easy to provide great answers to with a fairly short answer that shows exactly how to change YOUR code to do what you want.